# OpenSCAD beginner: help on making a curved object

Tags: 3d, geometry, autocad, openscad

I am teaching myself how to use openSCAD and I know the basics.  I decided to make a palm tree to practice using the software.  I used the following code to make the trunk:

```
linear_extrude(height = 50, center = true, convexity = 10, twist = 200)
circle(r = 1);
```

Which resulted in the following object:
[image]
Next for the top of the palm tree I wanted to create a 2D polygon, then rotate it 360 degrees.  The polygon would look something like this:
[image]

The polygon requires a series of points and this would be really hard since there is curved edges.  Is there an easier way to make the palm tree leaves?

Comment: You could find a palm tree silhouette on the web, trace it to create a vector (in Inkscape), edit it to remove the tree trunk and one side of the vector, save that as an SVG, then import the SVG into OpenSCAD and rotate extrude it.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple: use 3d shapes like cubes.
The code below could be obviously generated from a for loop.

```
translate([0, 0, 25]){
    linear_extrude(height = 50, center = true, convexity = 10, twist = 200)
        circle(r = 1);
}

translate([0, 0, 40]){cylinder(10, 1, 2);}


translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 20, 0]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 20, 20]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 20, 40]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 20, 60]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 20, 80]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 20, 100]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 20, 120]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 20, 140]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 20, 160]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 20, 180]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 20, 200]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 20, 220]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 20, 240]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 20, 260]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 20, 280]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 20, 300]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 20, 320]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 20, 340]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}

translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 2, 0]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 0, 20]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 2, 40]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 0, 60]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 0, 80]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 2, 100]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 0, 120]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 2, 140]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 2, 160]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 2, 180]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 0, 200]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 2, 220]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 0, 240]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 2, 260]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 2, 280]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 0, 300]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 0, 320]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
translate([0, 0, 50]){rotate([0, 0, 340]){cube([10, 5, 1]);}}
```

Answer (score 0):

//here is one way to do it but I feel it doesn't really represent a palm tree very well.

```
translate([0,0,20])
rotate_extrude()
rotate([0,0,90])
difference(){
union(){
difference(){
circle(r = 15,$fn = 100);
translate([-20,0])
circle(r = 30, $fn = 100);
}

translate([.2,0])
scale([.7,.8])
difference(){
circle(r = 15,$fn = 100);
translate([-20,0])
circle(r = 30, $fn = 100);
}

translate([.2,0])
scale([.5,.6])
difference(){
circle(r = 15,$fn = 100);
translate([-20,0])
circle(r = 30, $fn = 100);
}
translate([5,0])
rotate([0,0,45])
square(center = true,[1.5,1.5]);
 }

translate([15,-15])
square([30,30], center = true);
}




linear_extrude(height = 50, center = true, convexity = 10, twist = 200)
circle(r = 1);
```